# Randomise web scraping Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the below script to pull 10 videos from a video website. Each time it runs it pulls the same 10 videos. Instead I want it to pull 10 different videos each time. How can I achieve this?

I have been experimenting with adding `videos = random.choice(video)` amongst other things.

```
def link(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'     
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    videos = list(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json', limit=10))
    for video in videos:
        if '.mp4' in video.string:   
            try:
                video = json.loads(video.string.strip()) 
                r = requests.get(video['contentUrl'], stream=True)
                filename = video['contentUrl'].split('/')[-1]
                with open("/Users/path/Desktop/Test/" + filename, 'wb') as fd:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        fd.write(chunk)
            except Exception:
                print(Exception)

link('somewebsite.com')
```

Comment: [Pynative](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/) As it's suggests, maybe you were not so far. Try with `random_videos = random.sample(videos, 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the website gives you more than 10 videos per request.
I think that the suggestion of @MichaelMoretti is the easiest way, but ineffective on a list of 10 elements.
So maybe the solution is, first of all, load all videos removing the "limit"
`videos = list(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json'))`
and then use *sample()* to get 10 random videos.

EDIT:
This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import random
def link(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'     
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    videos = list(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json'))
    videos = random.sample(videos, 10)
    for video in videos:
        if '.mp4' in video.string:   
            try:
                video = json.loads(video.string.strip()) 
                r = requests.get(video['contentUrl'], stream=True)
                filename = video['contentUrl'].split('/')[-1]
                with open("/Users/path/Desktop/Test/" + filename, 'wb') as fd:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        fd.write(chunk)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

link('http://www.shutterstock.com/video/search?sort=random')
```

Comment: Using this website as my example https://www.shutterstock.com/video/search?sort=random - each page has multiple videos. If I take off the "limit" and apply it to the sample, the "limit" no longer works and all the videos download. I wonder if I should randomise the page instead of the list, maybe that is simpler?

Comment: The videos into the script are in a fixed list that is sorted at runtime, so doesn't matter what you put into your query string. The only solution that comes to mind is the one in the answer. I tried that on my computer and it seems to work. Anyway, I'm going to edit the answer, inserting  the code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got your list made.  Now you just need to randomize it.  You should be able to leverage

`import random`

and randomize your list, like this:

```
videos = list(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json', limit=10))
random.shuffle(videos)
    for video in videos:
```

Just toss that import at the top of your code with all your other imports (like BeautifulSoup) and you should be good to go!

If you want the website to just return 10 random videos you need to change how you request those videos.  How would you get your browser to return 10 random videos? What parameters would you pass? And then mock up the URL to do the same.  If the site is always returning 10 random videos, then there would not be much you could do :)

Comment: This seems like it would work but the code still downloads the same 10 videos each time it runs.